# Qemu read guest ram from host application

Tags: qemu

I have a host application which needs to access qemu physical address. For a RAM memory region.
I am not able to figure out the right way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

I am currently thinking of adding a socket server to the QEMU event loop to do this. But am not able to find the documentation for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the `static inline void cpu_physical_memory_read(hwaddr addr,void *buf, hwaddr len)` function in QEMU to read data from the RAM. This function is designed to read from the physical memory, making it suitable for your scenario.

Here's a basic example of how you might use it:

```
hwaddr guest_address = 0x12345678;  // Replace with the actual guest address
size_t read_size = 100;  // Replace with the actual size you want to read

// Allocate a buffer to store the read data
uint8_t read_buffer[read_size];

cpu_physical_memory_read(guest_addr, buffer, size);

printf("Read data from guest RAM: ");
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    printf("%02X ", read_buffer[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run qemu with gdb server enabled (-s), connect to the gdb server (TCP port 1234) and send your commands for memory reads to it.